# Visual Studio 2019 text editor bounces starting in v16.11.10

Tags: visual-studio-2019, windows-11

I'm on `VS2019 v16.11.10` on Windows 11.

This weird problem never happened prior to `VS2019 v16.11.10`: Frequently after making a code change, or cutting/pasting text in the text editor, the entire contents of the editor window literally bounces up and down maybe a millimeter or 1/2 millimeter. It's a small amount but extremely noticeable and annoying. It doesn't happen every time, but at least 3 times per minute while I am actively coding, and sometimes more like 5 times per minute. It doesn't happen after a typical keystroke, but usually after something a little more major like cut/paste/enter/reformat, etc.

Something changed in this latest version. Wondering if anyone else has seen this and if you know how it can be stopped.